# Why can't we return the timeOut by itself as opposed to creating a new Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm working through YDKJS and reviewing the Promises chapter.

In this section, it shows how we can add synchrony to what's happening in the then:

```
var p = Promise.resolve( 21 );

p.then( function(v){
    console.log( v );   // 21

    // create a promise to return
    return new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
        // introduce asynchrony!
        setTimeout( function(){
            // fulfill with value `42`
            resolve( v * 2 );
        }, 100 );
    } );
} )
.then( function(v){
    // runs after the 100ms delay in the previous step
    console.log( v );   // 42
} );
```

It then says: *"That's incredibly powerful! Now we can construct a sequence of however many async steps we want, and each step can delay the next step (or not!), as necessary."*

But why does the new `Promise` need to be created? Why can't we just return the `setTimeout`? Surely it'll only proceed to then after the timeout has executed? Or is that the whole point, that it doesn't?

Comment: @Pointy, no, setTimeout returns an identifier, which could be used in clearTimeout.

Comment: @YuriyYakym oh of course; need more coffee I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is that the whole point, that it doesn't?

Yes, `setTimeout` does return immediately, executing the callback *asynchronously* instead of blocking. The `then` callback will return long before those 100ms are gone by. To make it defer the next step, you need to return a promise from the `then` callback - and `setTimeout` doesn't give us one, so we need to create it explicitly using `new Promise`.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` returns timer identifier (which could be used in `clearTimeout` later). So if you return the result of `setTimeout` you will immediately resolve promise with timer identifier value.